# What does "Ideal boiler" mean in Christie's After the Funeral?

Tags: meaning, agatha-christie, after-the-funeral

In the book *After the funeral* by Agatha Christie, there is a passage when the Dr informs Susan of poison to Miss Gilchrist.

During their search for the wedding cake, the Dr asks Susan where the wrapping paper came from. This is what comes after that.

> Here they were not successful and Susan said that it had probably gone into the **Ideal boiler**.

What does *Ideal boiler* mean here? Is it literally referring to a boiler? If yes then what does the entire sentence mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the capital "I" in "Ideal boiler", this almost certainly refers to a boiler made by the Ideal Boilers company. According to this [web-page](https://www.cleverenergyboilers.co.uk/uncategorized/worcester-bosch-vs-ideal-boilers/):

> Ideal Boilers is a British company that still manufactures its
> products in Yorkshire. The company has a long history in the heating
> industry, stretching back more than a century, and is a very well
> known name in the UK.

A common configuration was to have an open fire, a hot water boiler, and an oven all in one unit. Presumably the wrapping paper had been put into the fire to dispose of it, rather than throwing it into the rubbish.